# Multiple JOIN mysql

Tags: mysql

Quiero hacer una consulta usando JOIN ya tengo la mayor parte de la consulta realizada, este es mi consulta actualmente

```
SELECT user_nicename, display_name, post_title, 
REPLACE(REPLACE(result_for, 'final', 'Tarea'),'quiz', 'Cuestionario'), 
generate_date, grade_name,e arned_percent
FROM wpam_tutor_gradebooks_results   wpar
JOIN wpam_users wpau **ON** wpau.ID = wpar.user_id
LEFT JOIN wpam_posts wpap **ON** wpap.ID = wpar.course_id
order by display_name asc
```

Lo que quiero hacer es reemplazar la tabla `result_for` (contiene datos de que si son "cuestionario" o "tareas/quiz" nada mas) usando el **join** con la tabla `wpam_posts` (ya lo utilice anteriomente en la consulta) que me daria el nombre de esos cuestionario o tareas reemplazando el ID ya sea del quiz, etc por el nombre del quiz, asi como lo hice aqui con el nombre del curso

```
LEFT JOIN wpam_posts wpap ON wpap.ID = wpar.course_id
```

y lo puese aqui "display_name"

pero resulta que el nombre del curso,cuestionario y tareas tambien esta almacenado en la misma tabla `wpam_posts` y en la misma columna `post_title` y no quiero que esten en la mima columna, sino en diferentes. asi como en la siguiente imagen
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tabla wpam_users
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tabla wpam_posts
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tabla wpam_tutor_gradebooks_results
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Podrías agregar la estructura que tiene cada una de tus tablas?

Comment: Ya actualize la pregunta @Sr1871 , le agregue las tablas

Comment: pero no sería tema de columna? qué tienen que ver los joins? en wpm_posts no existe la columna display_name

Comment: creo que tienes razon, es que no tengo gran conocimiento de mysql, lo que pasa que si el curso, los quiz, etc tienen su propio id pero donde estan sus nombre, están en el misma columna todos, y como le haría para hacer lo que tengo pensado como en la imagen de la primer tabla, que me muestre el nombre del quiz, en otra columna

Comment: display_name  esta en la tabla wpam_users, ese lo ocupe para agregar el nombre del usuario

Comment: para iniciar, dices que en display_name está todo, pero solo veo que tiene un dato y no creo que quieras dividir la palabra en columnas? entonces mejor pasa un ejemplo mínimo verificable, es bien sencillo de replicar en páginas como https://dbfiddle.uk/, colocas tus scripts de create table, inserts y puebla tus tablas para poder verlo con detalle y editas la pregunta.

Comment: disculpame los nombres de donde se almacena  los nombre del curso, quiz tec se llama post_title en la tabla wpam_posts

Comment: No entiendo el problema.. podes dar un ejemplo de la salida que queres?